# Clarify the sequence of events in a Spring MVC ORM web app project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-orm

My professor gave a sample Spring MVC ORM project with Hibernate but I can not figure out the sequence of events involved, in particular about the usage of service business object.
This is just a little part of the project, just to make my ideas clearer.

domain:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "department")
public class Department implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long uid;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="department",cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

    public Department() {
    }

    public Department(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

// getters, setters, hashcode() and equals(), toString()...
```

controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/department")
public class DepartmentController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("departmentBO")
    private DepartmentBO departmentBO;

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DepartmentController.class);

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String departmentHome(Model model) {
        logger.debug("department home() invoked");

        List<Department> list = departmentBO.findAllDepartments();
        model.addAttribute("list", list);
        return "departments";
    }
// i'll paste just the first controller ;)
```

business:

```
public interface DepartmentBO {

  public void delete(long uid);

  public List<Department> findAllDepartments();

  public Department findByUid(Long uid);

  public void save(Department department);

  public void update(Department department);  
}
```

business/impl:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DepartmentBoImpl implements DepartmentBO {

    @Autowired
    private DepartmentDAO departmentDao;

    static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DepartmentBoImpl.class);

    @Override
    public void save(Department department) {
        departmentDao.save(department);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Department department) {
        departmentDao.update(department);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(long uid) {
       departmentDao.delete(uid);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Department> findAllDepartments() {
        return departmentDao.findAllDepartments();
    }

    @Override
    public Department findByUid(Long uid) throws DataAccessException {
        return departmentDao.findByUid(uid);
    }
}
```

dao:

```
public interface DepartmentDAO {
  public void delete(long uid);

  public List<Department> findAllDepartments();

  public Department findByUid(Long uid);

  public void save(Department user);

  public void update(Department user); 
}
```

dao/impl:

```
@Repository
public class DepartmentDAOImplSf implements DepartmentDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public void delete(long uid) {
        Department department = (Department) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .get(Department.class, uid);
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(department);
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Department department) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(department);
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Department department) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(department);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Department> findAllDepartments() {
        List<Department> list = (List<Department>) sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession()
                .createQuery("FROM Department").list();

        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public Department findByUid(Long uid) {
        Department department = (Department) sessionFactory
                .getCurrentSession().get(Department.class, uid);
        return department;
    }
}
```

I know that the order is: domain model -> controller-> service -> dao ->db, but why use a DepartmentBO? and why DepartmentBoImpl autowired DepartmentDao? Who of them act first? Something that i'm not understanding is messing up my conception of how it works and the sequence of the process..
Thanks for your help ;)

EDIT: "

In few words my question is, what is the sequence of this code? user goes on the /home page that redirect on "departments" page. But what happen before this --> "List list = departmentBO.findAllDepartments();" ?;)

Comment: There are lots of design and architecture behind thes. Dependency Injection, Programming through interface, Data Access Pattern etc to name few. There are several online articles to follow.

Comment: i know that there are those things happening, but my question is, what is the sequence of this code? user goes on the indexpage that redirect on "departments". But what happen behind this --> "List<Department> list = departmentBO.findAllDepartments();"  ? ;)

Comment: When the departmentBO. findAllDepartments() method is invoked it delegates to Hibernate's sessionFactory, gets session and create a Query as and return the resultset as list of Department. It is basically querying the DB with given query statement. To know more, you have to see Hibernate Framework Documentation.

Comment: I appreciate your explanation, but i think my question is simplier, why DepartmentBO and DepartmentDao have almost the same code? And how and why one use the other one implementation?

Comment: In the architecture of Application Development, there are different tier consisting of Presentation, Business, Data Access and others. Here, DepartmentBO is in Business layers. This layer will do all business related work like, sending notification to admin when some department is updated or deleted (Probably not the best example). So, all these kinds of work are done here. DepartmentDao is in Data Access layer, whose responsibility is to communicate with database. No other work is done here. This create clean & maintainable code and helps for extendibility in future.

Comment: Decoupling the processes is ok, i just don't get why there is the injection of a dao bean in BoImpl class :(

Comment: Let me ask you, how you think it would make sense to you? The reason for Dao being injected in the Service is because Service might need to update, insert or delete in the DB. A Service might contain multiple DAO since the service might do various transactions.

Comment: That is the answer i needed! I just did not understand the reason of the injection, i wanted to know the processes involved in that particular situation :) could you give me some reference to articles or guide that explain this? :)

Answer (score 0):

When the departmentBO.findAllDepartments() method is called if you look at the code it invokes the sessionFactory. That is an internal factory class in Hibernate that basically builds a transactional connection to the DB in order to run a query. You are defining the query in the createQuery method and then ultimately executing it with the list() method. These two methods are part of the database session that Hibernate has instantiated.

Departments Page -> departmentBO.findAllDepartments() -> sessionFactory -> createQuery -> list()

Or in pseudo code-ish

Departments Page -> execute findAllDepartments method -> fetch / build a database connection -> define the query -> execute the query -> Return the list!

Comment: Very nice answer, but can you explain me the usage of DepartmentBO and DepartmentDao?

Comment: They are the interfaces. These define abstract methods which are inherited and implemented by the classes that implement the interface.
See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html for further details...

Comment: I know that, but why the DepartmentBOImpl uses a DepartmentDao bean?could you give me just a simple explanation?

Comment: Because one is business logic and one is data access logic? If that's what you are asking? The classes are logically different, even if the code inside them looks similar. One provides the actual business logic and one handles only the logic involved with data access.

They look so similar here because this is quite a simple example, but in the real world you could have complex business logic that needs to happen that isn't directly related to the task of actually saving and retrieving the data.

Comment: Decoupling the processes is ok, i just don't get why there is the injection of a dao bean in BoImpl class :(